# Update a column of table with random entry from another table

Tags: postgresql

```
update testdata.test
   set abcd = (select abc 
                 from DATA1
                order by random()
                limit 1
              )
```

Doing this only makes one random entry from table DATA1 is getting populated in all the rows of TEST table.

What I need is - > to generate each row with random entry from DATA 1 table to TEST table

Comment: So could a given random value `abc` appear more than once in the result set?

Comment: DATA1 always has more rows then test?..

Comment: @Tim Biegelesian yes it can appear

Comment: @Vao Tsun DATA1 has less rows than test data..but it doesn't matter I just want populate random data from DATA1 to test ..so even if there are 4 rows in DATA1 these must appear randomly in TEST table with how much ever the test columns is filled

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate random data from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510958/populate-random-data-from-another-table)

Answer (score 1):

Reference the outer table from the subquery so that it becomes a correlated subquery. Then it has to be executed for every row:

```
UPDATE testdata.test
SET abcd = (SELECT CASE WHEN test.abcd IS NOT DISTINCT FROM test.abcd
                        THEN abc 
                   END
            FROM data1
            ORDER BY random()
            LIMIT 1
           );
```

Comment: I get an error at  distinct (select case when ipreal is not distinct) in postgresql. and I tried using condition instead of distinct                           WHEN test.abcd <> test.abcd THEN abc     -> Query executes but NO Updation

Comment: sorry about that .. ERROR  - >Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "DISTINCT" 
Position: 70;

SET ipreal = (SELECT CASE WHEN ipreal IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ipreal

Comment: You must be using something else than plain PostgreSQL then, because I ran the statement above and did not get such an error.

Comment: You are kidding, right? 8.0.2? But even this ancient version (install at least the latest point release!) had the `IS DISTINCT FROM` operator.