# Populate random data from another table

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

```
update dataset1.test
   set column4 = (select column1 
                 from dataset2
                 order by random()
                 limit 1
                 )
```

I have to update dataset1 of column 4 with each row updating a random entry from dataset 2 column.. But by far now in this above query I get only one random entry in all the rows of dataset1 and its all same which I want it to be random.

Comment: Some questions: Would you allow one value from `dataset2` be used multiple times on `dataset1`, or does each value have to be used at most once? Does `dataset2` have at least as many rows as `dataset1`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQl Update from table of random Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560392/sql-update-from-table-of-random-names) .  Assumes you have a numeric ID on dataset2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redshift: Update or Insert each row in column with random data from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535038/redshift-update-or-insert-each-row-in-column-with-random-data-from-another-tabl)

Comment: Please do not double-post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**SETUP**

Let's start by assuming your tables an data are the following ones.
Note that I assume that `dataset1` has a primary key (it can be a composite one, but, for the sake of simplicity, let's make it an integer):

```
CREATE TABLE dataset1
(
     id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
     column4 TEXT
) ;

CREATE TABLE dataset2
(
    column1 TEXT
) ;
```

We fill both tables with sample data

```
INSERT INTO dataset1
    (id, column4)
SELECT
    i, 'column 4 for id ' || i
FROM
    generate_series(101, 120) AS s(i);

INSERT INTO dataset2
    (column1)
SELECT
    'SOMETHING ' || i
FROM 
    generate_series (1001, 1020) AS s(i) ;
```

Sanity check:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT column4) FROM dataset1 ;
```

```
| count |
| ----: |
|    20 |
```

---

## Case 1: number of rows in dataset1 <= rows in dataset2

We'll perform a complete shuffling. Values from dataset2 will be used once, and no more than once.

**EXPLANATION**

In order to make an update that shuffles all the values from `column4` in a
random fashion, we need some intermediate steps.

First, for the `dataset1`, we need to create a list (relation) of tuples `(id, rn)`, that
are just:

```
(id_1,   1),
(id_2,   2),
(id_3,   3),
...
(id_20, 20)
```

Where `id_1`, ..., `id_20` are the ids present on `dataset1`.
They can be of any type, they need not be consecutive, and they can be composite.

For the `dataset2`, we need to create another list of `(column_1,rn)`, that looks like:

```
(column1_1,  17),
(column1_2,   3),
(column1_3,  11),
...
(column1_20, 15)
```

In this case, the second column contains all the values 1 .. 20, but shuffled.

Once we have the two relations, we `JOIN` them `ON ... rn`. This, in practice, produces yet another list of tuples with `(id, column1)`, where the pairing has been done randomly. We use these pairs to update `dataset1`.

**THE REAL QUERY**

This can all be done (clearly, I hope) by using some CTE (`WITH` statement) to hold the intermediate relations:

```
WITH original_keys AS
(
    -- This creates tuples (id, rn), 
    -- where rn increases from 1 to number or rows
    SELECT 
        id, 
        row_number() OVER  () AS rn
    FROM 
        dataset1
)
, shuffled_data AS
(
    -- This creates tuples (column1, rn)
    -- where rn moves between 1 and number of rows, but is randomly shuffled
    SELECT 
        column1,
        -- The next statement is what *shuffles* all the data
        row_number() OVER  (ORDER BY random()) AS rn
    FROM 
        dataset2
)
-- You update your dataset1
-- with the shuffled data, linking back to the original keys
UPDATE
    dataset1
SET
    column4 = shuffled_data.column1
FROM
    shuffled_data
    JOIN original_keys ON original_keys.rn = shuffled_data.rn
WHERE
    dataset1.id = original_keys.id ;
```

Note that the *trick* is performed by means of:

```
row_number() OVER (ORDER BY random()) AS rn
```

The [`row_number()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) that produces as many consecutive numbers as there are rows, starting from 1.
These numbers are randomly shuffled because the `OVER` clause takes all the data and sorts it randomly.

**CHECKS**

We can check again:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT column4) FROM dataset1 ;
```

```
| count |
| ----: |
|    20 |
```

```
SELECT * FROM dataset1 ;
```

```
 id | column4       
--: | :-------------
101 | SOMETHING 1016
102 | SOMETHING 1009
103 | SOMETHING 1003
...
118 | SOMETHING 1012
119 | SOMETHING 1017
120 | SOMETHING 1011
```

**ALTERNATIVE**

Note that this can also be done with subqueries, by simple substitution, instead of CTEs. That might improve performance in some occasions:

```
UPDATE
    dataset1
SET
    column4 = shuffled_data.column1
FROM
    (SELECT 
        column1,
        row_number() OVER  (ORDER BY random()) AS rn
    FROM 
        dataset2
    ) AS shuffled_data
    JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        id, 
        row_number() OVER  () AS rn
    FROM 
        dataset1
    ) AS original_keys ON original_keys.rn = shuffled_data.rn
WHERE
    dataset1.id = original_keys.id ;
```

And again...

```
SELECT * FROM dataset1;
```

```
 id | column4       
--: | :-------------
101 | SOMETHING 1011
102 | SOMETHING 1018
103 | SOMETHING 1007
...
118 | SOMETHING 1020
119 | SOMETHING 1002
120 | SOMETHING 1016
```

---

You can check the whole setup and experiment at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=736f291a68bd7aae52b72585a2ec25e6)*

NOTE: if you do this with very large datasets, don't expect it to be extremely fast. Shuffling a very big deck of cards is expensive.

---

## Case 2: number of rows in dataset1 > rows in dataset2

In this case, values for `column4` can be repeated several times.

The easiest possibility I can think of (probably, not an efficient one, but easy to understand) is to create a function `random_column1`, marked as `VOLATILE`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION random_column1() 
    RETURNS TEXT
    VOLATILE      -- important!
    LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
    SELECT
        column1
    FROM
        dataset2
    ORDER BY
        random()
    LIMIT
        1 ;
$$ ;
```

And use it to update:

```
UPDATE
    dataset1
SET
    column4 = random_column1();
```

This way, some values from `dataset2` *might* not be used at all, whereas others  *will* be used more than once.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ab285b97fc366ba3bab42f5c5b51f0ff)*

Comment: hey your queries seems legit..but there one thing I forgot to mention that dataset1 is larger than dataset2 .. so for example dataset2 can have 50 data and if dataset1 has 100 data.  - > dataset1 should be updated with random values from dataset2 even if the value occurs 10 times

Comment: You should edit your question and add this piece of information. Any possible answer will be much influenced by that.

Comment: See **Case 2** in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Better is to reference the outer table from the subquery. Then the subquery has to be evalued for every row:

```
update dataset1.test
   set column4 = (select
        case when dataset1.test.column4 = dataset1.test.column4
             then column1 end
        from dataset2
        order by random()
        limit 1
   )
```