# Redshift: Update or Insert each row in column with random data from another table

Tags: amazon-redshift

```sql
update testdata.dataset1
   set abcd = (select abc 
               from dataset2
               order by random()
               limit 1
              )
```

Doing this only makes one random entry from table `dataset2` is getting populated in all the rows of `dataset1` table.

What I need is to generate each row with random entry from `dataset2` table to `dataset1` table.

Notice: `dataset1` can be greater than `dataset2`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate random data from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510958/populate-random-data-from-another-table)

Comment: sorry I had to create one for redshift and postgree..So I had two.

Comment: Why did you need to create two questions? You could ask one question with both tags. However, you should always indicate in your question which database your are using because the answers can be different (especially for Redshift).

Comment: yes I will correct that. Sorry for creating two questions. could have edited first post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query 1**

You should pass `abcd` into your subquery to prevent "optimizing".

```sql
UPDATE dataset1
    SET abcd = (SELECT abc
                FROM dataset2
                WHERE abcd = abcd
                ORDER BY random()
                LIMIT 1
               );
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f1849c/4/0)

**Query 2**

The query below should be faster on plain PostgreSQL.

```sql
UPDATE dataset1
    SET abcd = (SELECT abc
                FROM dataset2
                WHERE abcd = abcd
                OFFSET floor(random()*(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dataset2))
                LIMIT 1
               );
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a8ac6/5/1)

However, as you have reported, it is not the case on Redshift, which is a columnar storage.

**Query 3**

Fetching all the records from `dataset2` in a single query would be more efficient than fetching records one by one. Let's test:

```
UPDATE dataset1 original
SET abcd = fake.abc FROM 
              (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY random()) AS id, abc FROM dataset2) AS fake
               WHERE original.id % (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dataset2) = fake.id - 1;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2cd5e/9)

Note that the integer `id` column should exist in `dataset1`.
Also, for `dataset1.id`'s that are greater than the number of records in `dataset2`, `abcd`'s are predictable.

**Query 4**

Let's create the integer `fake_id` column in `dataset1`, prefill it with random values and perform join on `dataset1.fake_id = dataset2.id`:

```
UPDATE dataset1
SET fake_id = floor(random()*(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dataset2)) + 1;  

UPDATE dataset1
SET abcd = abc
FROM dataset2
WHERE dataset1.fake_id = dataset2.id;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fd66ec/6)

**Query 5**

If you don't want to add `fake_id` column to `dataset1`, let's calculate `fake_id`'s "on the fly":

```
UPDATE dataset1
SET abcd = abc
FROM (
SELECT with_fake_id.id, dataset2.abc FROM 
(SELECT dataset1.id,  floor(RANDOM()*(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dataset2) + 1) AS fake_id FROM dataset1) AS with_fake_id
JOIN dataset2 ON with_fake_id.fake_id = dataset2.id ) AS joined
WHERE dataset1.id = joined.id;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fd66ec/9)

---

**Performance**

On plain PostgreSQL, query 4 seems to be the most efficient.
I'll try to compare performance on a trial DC1.Large instance.

Comment: is that redshift?

Comment: this seems to be working but its slow for for updating 3 mil rows ...any way of optimizing the query  or any other alternate to make it little faster?

Comment: UPDATE testdata.ipdummy2 not successful
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
update testdata.ipdummy2
    set ipreal = (select ip
                from testdata.ipdummy3
                where ipreal is not null or ipreal is null...

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: caught signal
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
error:  caught signal
code:      518
context:   unknown
location:  unknown:-1
process:   padbmaster [pid=21559]
-----------------------------------------------;
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 4.88s

Comment: for above comment error was in offset I guess..I'm not sure though

Comment: Well, try to replace `WHERE abcd IS NOT NULL OR abcd IS NULL` with`WHERE abcd = abcd` in the second query. Is it working?